# Expanding and Collapsing a tableView cell upto label's text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a label in a **TableViewCell** in which there are more than one lines of text. Initially on the label it shows only one line. I have a button on that cell. I want to expand the cell by clicking on the button upto the hight of the label's text.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"tabCell";
   _cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Configure the cell...
   NSManagedObject *device = [self.persons objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

   UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel*)[_cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
  nameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [device valueForKey:@"name"]];

   UILabel *dateLabel = (UILabel *)[_cell.contentView viewWithTag:3];
   dateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[device valueForKey:@"date"]];

   UILabel *descLabel = (UILabel *)[_cell.contentView viewWithTag:4];
//descTextView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[device valueForKey:@"desc"]];


   UIImageView *personImage = (UIImageView *)[_cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
   UIImage *personImg = [UIImage imageWithData:[device valueForKey:@"image"]];
   personImage.image = personImg;

    UIButton *viewMoreButton = (UIButton *)[_cell.contentView viewWithTag:5];
    [viewMoreButton addTarget:self
             action:@selector(myAction)
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    NSAttributedString *attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[device valueForKey:@"desc"]
                                                                 attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:17]}];


    reqFrame=[attrString boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(descLabel.frame.size.height, CGFLOAT_MAX)options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                  context:nil];


    descLabel.attributedText = attrString;




    return _cell;
}

- (void)myAction{

   //what to write here?

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all it is not a good practice to build cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Use `willDisplayCell` instead. [See here why](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:).

Secondly to do what you want you have to set desired height in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`. Once this accomplished, within your button selector call to refresh specific cells using

```
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPathOfYourCell, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

The implementation is similar:

```
- (void)buttonSelector
{
    myLabel.text = @"YOUR TEXT";
    [myLabel sizeToFit];
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPathOfYourCell, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    ...
    return yourLabel.height;
}
```

Comment: But how to expand upto the height of label's text sir?

Comment: Within heightForRowAtIndexPath return height of the label. in order to get label there either store it in some collection or give it a tag and retreive it using [view subViewWithTag:tag]

Comment: At first the label is showing only 2 lines of the text. But after clicking on the button the cell and as well as the label's height will expand and will show the full text. This is my requirement. @Misha

Comment: Good. what I wrote will definitely help you. Prior to this within button selector you can assign full text to your button and call [label sizeToFit] to make label set minimum width and height needed to show whole text.

Comment: Can we move this discussion to chat @Misha?

Answer (score 0):

Anyhow need to get **reference of the cell** and **indexPath** on which the button is tapped in your `myAction()`.

Create a private variable `CGFloat newCellHeight;` and initialize it to 0.0.
Let reference to the associated cell is `selectedCell` and selected index path is `indexPathOfTappedCell`.

```
- (void)myAction{
        UILabel *descLabel = (UILabel*)[selectedCell.contentView viewWithTag:4];
        [descLabel sizeToFit]; // Automatically increases the height of the label as required
        newCellHeight = CGRectGetMaxY(descLabel.frame) + 10.0; // Extra padding 10.0
        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPathOfTappedCell] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```

Now add the following TableView delegate method in your view controller

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (indexPath.section == indexPathOfTappedCell.section &&
        indexPath.row == indexPathOfTappedCell.row ) {
        return newCellHeight;
    }
    return 44.0; // Suppose default height is 44.0
}
```

Comment: indexPathOfTappedCell and indexPath.row should be the same. Isn't it? @Sauvik?

Comment: indexPath.row which one? Index path contains section and row.  Where indexPath.row only contains the row number. No Section value is stored.

Comment: There is only one section. You just tell me what should I write in the action of my button? I just can't get this thing done from 2 days. :( @ Sauvik Da

Comment: The indexPath.section == indexPathOfTappedCell.section change it to indexPath.section == 0. Anyway are you ready with the reference of the cell and index path in you button tap event?

Comment: I have modified the function accordingly, please let me know whether it is working or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81445/discussion-between-sauvik-dolui-and-ipeter).

Answer (score 0):

you need to maintain two variables, just give tag to your button, and detect in action by its tag to reload that particular cell and another BOOL variable to detect if button touched. You should calculate height in heightForRowAtIndexPath method. I am posting code, it may help you

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

if(isReadMoreButtonTouched && [indexPath row]== indexOfReadMoreButton) {
    NSString *yourText = [arr1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; // your text

    NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir Next" size:14], NSFontAttributeName,
                                [UIColor grayColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                nil]; // set custom attributes

    NSAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:yourText attributes:attributes];

    CGRect paragraphRect = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(625, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                                        options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                                                        context:nil]; //here 625 is width of label

    NSLog(@"height = %f", paragraphRect.size.height);
    return paragraphRect.size.height;

}
else{

    return 200; //default height taken in storyboard
}
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

cell.lblKB.text = [arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.lblDetail.text = [arr1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSString *yourText = [arr1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir Next" size:14], NSFontAttributeName,
                            GrayColor, NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                            nil];   //your custom attributes

NSAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:yourText attributes:attributes];

CGRect paragraphRect = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(625, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                                    options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                                                    context:nil];

NSLog(@"height = %f", paragraphRect.size.height);

if (paragraphRect.size.height<200) {
    cell.btnMore.hidden = YES;
}
else{
    cell.btnMore.hidden = NO;
}

cell.btnMore.tag = indexPath.row;

return cell;
}


// action of button click

-(IBAction)MoreBtnClicked:(id)sender {

if (!isReadMoreButtonTouched) {
    isReadMoreButtonTouched = YES;
}
else{

    isReadMoreButtonTouched = NO;

}

indexOfReadMoreButton = [sender tag];

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[sender tag] inSection:0];
[self.tblKB reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic]; //reload that cell of your tableview

}
```